# SQL и прикладные программы

Tags: sql

Как вызвать в SQL прикладные программы.

Comment: С ником Стандарт нельзя такого от SQL хотеть :-)

Comment: перед тем как задавать глупые вопросы почитали б сначала что такое SQL http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

в принцыпе в некоторых СУБД есть такие такая фича (или похожая) но опять же сам факт что вам нужен такой функционал наталкивает на мысль что вы пытаетесь решить какую-то проблему неправильно

Comment: Упрощенно алгоритм следующий:В базу данных MS Access в реальном масштабе времени поступают данные.Сразу же формируется запрос SQL,  по которому извлекаются из базы вместе с новыми архивные данные.Они  обрабатываются прикладной программой Wolfram в реальном масштабе времени. Прикладная программа активирует запрос SQL по которому обработанные данные помещаются в базу данных.Процесс повторяется с приходом новых данных в базу (цикл 10-20 сек).
Re:Собственных средств обработки в SQL недостаточно.

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL, например, предоставляет хранимую процедуру [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), которая может выполнить что-то в командной строке и даже вернуть результат.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что для задач, которые решает SQL, его собственных инструментов вполне достаточно. Однако вопрос стоит, так как стоит. Поэтому требуется узнать какую СУБД Вы используете. Язык SQL не предполагает таких возможностей.

Comment: Например, передать данные из SQL в прикладной пакет Wolfram Mathematika результаты обработки вернуть в SQL

Comment: какую конкретно СУБД вы используете?

Comment: Табличная база данных

Comment: *facepalm* Название-то у нее есть? MySQL? MS SQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle? FoxPro? MS Access? PervasiveSQL? SQLite? H2? DerbyDB?

Answer (score 0):

Вызов прикладной программы из SQL противоречит общей концепции БД - как способа хранения/обработки данных.

Если уж на то пошло всегда делается наоборот: есть некая прикладная программа, которая обращается к SQL - и чего-то из нее получает, но не наоборот.

Если есть этот Wolfram Matematica (если это нормальная прога, то она должна иметь интерфейс к SQL) - пусть она обращается к SQL берет оттуда данные и дальше обрабатывает.

**Update** Мельком глянул на [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/features/), ну конечно же он поддерживает чтение и выгрузку данных из/в SQL. Имеет встроенный язык, позволяющий манипулировать как с данными, так и различными алгоритмами. Так что делайте из нее полноценный слой бизнес логики, а данные пусть лежать на SQL

Comment: > если это нормальная прога, то она должна иметь интерфейс к SQL

Простите, что?

Answer (score 0):

Не извращайтесь с SQLом, пишите вызов прикладных программ в прикладной программе, а SQL код для обработки данных используйте.

Comment: Упрощенно алгоритм следующий:В базу данных MS Access в реальном масштабе времени поступают данные.Сразу же формируется запрос SQL,  по которому извлекаются из базы вместе с новыми архивные данные.Они  обрабатываются прикладной программой Wolfram в реальном масштабе времени. Прикладная программа активирует запрос SQL по которому обработанные данные помещаются в базу данных.Процесс повторяется с приходом новых данных в базу (цикл 10-20 сек).
Re:Собственных средств обработки в SQL недостаточно.